# How to overwrite a publication from a package in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-publications

I need to overwrite a buggy publication from a package.

When I add the publication to the server startup I get

```
Ignoring duplicate publish named ...
```

Comment: Fork the thing, comment out the code..?

Comment: Umm. Isn't that overkill for just a small bug? And I loose the package convenience (i.e. auto update), right?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's any clean way to prevent the publication from working. I think your best bet is to either PR the package to fix the bug or fork it and remove the publication altogether. If I have some time I'll try to see how you can dirtily hide a publication from clients.